# Best way to convert the string with Byte sequence to Byte Array

Tags: c#, array, converting, byte

We had a `string` with `byte array` (hexadecimal) sequence, like: `"0x65,0x31,0xb6,0x9e,0xaf,0xd2,0x39,0xc9,0xad,0x07,0x78,0x99,0x73,0x52,0x91,0xf5,0x93,0x1a,0x49,0xc6"` and we need to recovery this sequence to `byte array` again.

We are using the following approach:

```
string byteSequence = "0x65,0x31,0xb6,0x9e,0xaf,0xd2,0x39,0xc9,0xad,0x07,0x78,0x99,0x73,0x52,0x91,0xf5,0x93,0x1a,0x49,0xc6";

byte[] myBytes = stringByteSequence.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();
```

This hash sequence it been generated by [this sample](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization#how-to-generate-password-hash):

```
string password = "<your password here>";

using (var cryptoProvider = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create())
{
    byte[] passwordHash = cryptoProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
    string result = "new byte[] { " + 
        String.Join(",", passwordHash.Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("x2")).ToArray())
         + " } ";
  
    //...
    // result = "new byte[] { 0x65,0x31,0xb6,0x9e,0xaf,0xd2,0x39,0xc9,0xad,0x07,0x78,0x99,0x73,0x52,0x91,0xf5,0x93,0x1a,0x49,0xc6 }"
    //...
}
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to do this conversion?

***Illustrative code, like:***

```
byte[] myBytes = byteSequence.Which.Method.I.Can.Use.To.Convert.It.To.Byte.Array.Again?();
```

Original sample (referenced link above):

```
new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
{
      Login = "Administrator-2",
      // Password as SHA1 hash
      Password = new byte[]{0xa9,
                 0x4a, 0x8f, 0xe5, 0xcc, 0xb1, 0x9b,
                 0xa6, 0x1c, 0x4c, 0x08, 0x73, 0xd3,
                 0x91, 0xe9, 0x87, 0x98, 0x2f, 0xbb,
                 0xd3}
}
```

Our main idea:

```
new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
{
      Login = "Administrator-2",
      // Password as SHA1 hash
      Password = configuration["MY_ENV_VAR_NAME"].Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16)).ToArray();

}
```

Comment: Please note that your edits seem to be responding directly to the answers provided. We take answer invalidation quite seriously here, so please make sure the answers still make sense after your edits.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: All right np! But the "edited code" do not change the main objective of question. Please read the first version of question and compare with the only remaining "answer" and tell me if this answer make sense...

Comment: Whyy downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why are you storing the hexadecimal hash like that, if you can just use plain hexadecimal it would be more readable and would prevent from adding unnecessary work.

For your current work, you can use extension methods to convert from hexadecimal string to bytes, and vise versa.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToHexadecimalSeparatedString(this byte[] bytes) => bytes != null ? string.Join(",", bytes.Select(x => $"0x{x:X2}")) : null;
    
    public static byte[] FromHexadecimalSeparatedString(this string hexadecimal)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexadecimal)) return null;
        return hexadecimal.Split(',').Select(x=> Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray();
    }
    
}
```

usage :

```
string byteSequence = "0x65,0x31,0xb6,0x9e,0xaf,0xd2,0x39,0xc9,0xad,0x07,0x78,0x99,0x73,0x52,0x91,0xf5,0x93,0x1a,0x49,0xc6";

byte[] bytes = byteSequence.FromHexadecimalSeparatedString();

string hexadecimal = bytes.ToHexadecimalSeparatedString();
```

so in your sample would be :

```
new BasicAuthAuthorizationUser
{
      Login = "Administrator-2",
      // Password as SHA1 hash
      Password = configuration["MY_ENV_VAR_NAME"].FromHexadecimalSeparatedString()

}
```

Although, I'm still not convinced of the way that hexadecimal is stored, if you planning to revert it to plain hexadecimal (no separators, and no hexadecimal prefix) then you might be interested in using the following extensions :

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ToHexadecimal(this byte[] bytes) => bytes != null ? string.Concat(bytes.Select(x => $"{x:X2}")) : null;
    
    public static byte[] FromHexadecimal(this string hexadecimal, string separater = null)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexadecimal)) return null;

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(separater))
        {
            hexadecimal = hexadecimal.Replace(separater, string.Empty);
        }

        var temp = hexadecimal.Replace("0x", string.Empty);

        byte[] bytes = new byte[temp.Length / 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(temp.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        
        return bytes;
    }
    
}
```

the following part is just for backward compatibility, to support the hashes that were already stored with separators. If all stored hashes are plain (no separators, no hexadecimal prefix) then, you can drop that part.

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(separater))
{
    hexadecimal = hexadecimal.Replace(separater, string.Empty);
}

var temp = hexadecimal.Replace("0x", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hey @iSR5 thanks for your time! The extension method is not the mais objetive. The main objetive is another "algorithm" to make the reverse conversion (string sequence to byte).

Comment: When you say "Not sure why are you storing the hexadecimal hash like that, if you can just use plain hexadecimal it would be more readable and would prevent from adding unnecessary work." What the better form to make it (store)? To avoid in "hard code"? The library (Hangfire) "requires" [SHA1 formated byte array hexadecimal](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization#basic-authentication).

Comment: In this cenario, we only store the "string byte sequence" generated by code semple: `cryptoProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password))...` (at the body of question) and after use `Joins`. [This method](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization#how-to-generate-password-hash) has been created by "Hangfire" library creators.

Comment: @Igor the better form would be either storing the original hash bytes (no conversion to string) or convert it to hexadecimal if needs to be stored as string (use `ToHexadecimal`). The `Hangfire` seems to only requires `byte[]` in `Password` property, so using the hash bytes that generated from `ComputeHash` with `Password` property would be enough. It's been done also in the source code take a look at `PasswordClear` property  https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Dashboard.Authorization/BasicAuthAuthorizationUser.cs

Comment: In the past I've tried to save only the result of `cryptoProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));` as `string`, and the password does not match when use it, is that what you meant? When you say: ..."better form would be either storing the original hash bytes (no conversion to string)"... Where I can store `byte[]` without convert it to string?

Comment: When I said: ..."In the past I've tried to save only the result of cryptoProvider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password)); as string"... More specifically this: `string result = "new byte[] { 101,49,182,158,175,210,57,201,173,7,120,153,115,82,145,245,147,26,73,198 }"` This hash do you mean, right? (the number sequence)

Comment: @Igor converting a `byte[]` to hexadecimal string (using your example) would result in something like this `6531B69EAFD239C9AD077899735291F5931A49C6` which then we can revert it to an actual `byte[]` using `FromHexadecimal` method. this would give you consistent results. The issue with comparing hashes you've experienced in the past might came from an inconsistent conversion between the `byte[]` and its `string` representation.

Comment: Thanks for clarification @iSR5, I will try it later and back here soon!

Comment: Hey @iSR5, sorry for the late reply... I've tried to use only `6531B69EAFD239C9AD077899735291F5931A49C6` and it's work's fine :)! Now I will try to remove/refactor the `for` loop on `FromHexadecimal` method. Do you have any another suggestion to avoid loop? (like `LINQ`). Thank's a lot!

Comment: @Igor I've never thought about it,  however, doing direct `Select` using `LINQ` won't do the job. But you could use `Enumerable.Range` instead. with something like `Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length / 2).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x * 2, 2), 16)).ToArray();`

Comment: Yeah, I've imagined/searched something like your suggestion or something like `Regex.Split(hexadecimal, @"(?<=\G.{2})", RegexOptions.Singleline).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray();`. With `LINQ` we now can try [Chunk](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0), like: `hexadecimal.Chunk(2).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 16)).ToArray();`

Comment: @Igor I've never used `Chunk` extension, but it doesn't matter on which way you choose the implementation as long as it gives the same output results. Just focus on readability and performance-wise, and more on what makes sense and what's not.

Comment: What method has used to "avoid" loop is trivial with base on ours requirements (redability/perf).